API is returning undefined search results
I am working on a mock movie website project and I have implemented an omdb API when I search a movie it is returning only movies that say undefined I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Also it is not implementing the css I have made for styling either not sure why.
this is my code and a link to the GitHub repo Github
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Nav from "../ui/Nav";
import axios from "axios";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faMagnifyingGlass } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const API_URL = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=cca6a59";

function Home() {
  const [searchItem, setSearchItem] = useState("");
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  function onSearch() {
    // console.log("search term", searchItem);
    setTimeout(() => {
      fetchMovies(searchItem);
      navigate(`/movies/${searchItem}`)
    })
    fetchMovies(searchItem);
  }
  async function fetchMovies(title) {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}&s=${title}`);
    setMovies(data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies("");
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <section id="landing">
        <div className="landing__container">
          <div className="landing__row">
            <h1 className="landing__header">
              America's favorite online movie search engine!
            </h1>
            <h3 className="landing__sub-header">
              Find your favorite movie here.
            </h3>
            <div className="search__container">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={searchItem}
                className="search__bar"
                placeholder="Search Movie Title"
                onChange={(event) => {
                  setSearchItem(event.target.value);
                }}
              />
              <button onClick={() => onSearch(movies)} className="input__btn">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMagnifyingGlass} />
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;

import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Nav from "../ui/Nav";

const API_URL = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=cca6a59";

function Movies() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  async function fetchMovies(title) {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}&s=${title}`);
    setMovies(data.Search);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies();
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
    <Nav />
      <div className="movie__row">
        <div className="movie__wrapper">
          {movies.map((movie) => (
            <div className="movie">
              <div className="movie__img" key={movie.id}>
                <img src={`${movie.Poster}`} alt="poster" />
                <div className="movies__content">
                  <h1>{movie.Title}</h1>
                  <h1>{movie.Year}</h1>
                  <p onClick={`${movie.imdbID}`}>SEE MORE</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Movies;


Can you attach a screenshot to your question too to illustrate the manifestation of the problem?

For Movies component you are calling fetchMovies without getting the title
 useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies();
  }, []);

so undefined is being passed in the url like so http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=cca6a59&s=undefined
You can fix it by getting the path parameter using useParams and correctly implementing useEffect like the below code
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Nav from "../ui/Nav";
import axios from "axios";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faMagnifyingGlass } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Home() {
  const [searchItem, setSearchItem] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  function onSearch() {
      navigate(`/movies/${searchItem}`)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <section id="landing">
        <div className="landing__container">
          <div className="landing__row">
            <h1 className="landing__header">
              America's favorite online movie search engine!
            </h1>
            <h3 className="landing__sub-header">
              Find your favorite movie here.
            </h3>
            <div className="search__container">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={searchItem}
                className="search__bar"
                placeholder="Search Movie Title"
                onChange={(event) => {
                  setSearchItem(event.target.value);
                }}
              />
              <button onClick={() => onSearch()} className="input__btn">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMagnifyingGlass} />
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;



import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Nav from "../ui/Nav";

const API_URL = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=cca6a59";

function Movies() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const params = useParams();
  const title = params.id;

  async function fetchMovies(title) {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}&s=${title}`);
    setMovies(data.Search);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies(title);
  }, [title]);

  
  return (
    <>
    <Nav />
      <div className="movie__row">
        <div className="movie__wrapper">
          {movies.map((movie) => (
            <div className="movie">
              <div className="movie__img" key={movie.id}>
                <img src={`${movie.Poster}`} alt="poster" />
                <div className="movies__content">
                  <h1>{movie.Title}</h1>
                  <h1>{movie.Year}</h1>
                  <p onClick={`${movie.imdbID}`}>SEE MORE</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Movies;




Thank you!! That did it I appreciate you so much I have been trying to figure this out for days!
